# Bokeh real time update x_axis after refresh

Tags: python, real-time, visualization, updates, bokeh

From the last days, I have been trying to use Bokeh to plot real-time data and display on a .html in order to be embeed in a webpage. I have sucessuly adapted one of the bokeh examples to my needs. I am using a buffer of 50 elements on the plot and I am noting the following behaviour:

1) In case I run the script and go to the browser the x_range fully adapts to incomming data and everything works correctly

2) If I click on "Refresh" on the browser the x_range stops to adapt to incoming data and freezes to the last value.

I tried to force the x_axis to initial and end values but the visualization behaves poorly.

I think I am not correctly understanding what does the "Refresh" hit impacts my code and how I can workaround this issue.

```
""" To view this example, first start a Bokeh server:

bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin=localhost:8000

And then load the example into the Bokeh server by
running the script:

python animated.py

in this directory. Finally, start a simple web server
by running:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer  (python 2)

or

python -m http.server  (python 3)

in this directory. Navigate to

http://localhost:8000/animated.html

"""
from __future__ import print_function

import io

from numpy import pi, cos, sin, linspace, roll

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.embed import server_session
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

fa = open('Accelerometer.txt', 'r')

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))
fg = figure(width=250, plot_height=250, title="RT-Test")
fg.line(x='x', y='y', color="olive", source=source)
fg.x_range.follow = "end"

# Visualization scale and aesthetics
fg.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
fg.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
fg.background_fill_color = "snow"

# add the plot to curdoc
curdoc().add_root(fg)

# open a session which will keep our local doc in sync with server
session = push_session(curdoc())

html = """
 <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    %s
  </body>
</html>
""" % server_session(fg, session_id=session.id, relative_urls=False)

with io.open("animated.html", mode='w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html)

print(__doc__)

def update():
    line = fa.readline().split(',')
    x = float(line[0])
    y = float(line[1])
    print(x, y)

    # construct the new values for all columns, and pass to stream
    new_data = dict(x=[x], y=[y])
    source.stream(new_data, rollover=50)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 100)

session.loop_until_closed() # run forever
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of usage of the Bokeh server, with the actual code running in a separate process and calling `session.loop_until_closed`, is ***discouraged in the strongest terms***. In the next release, all of the examples of this sort will be deleted, and mentions of this approach removed from the docs. This usage is inherently inferior in many ways, [as outlined here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.13/docs/user_guide/server.html#connecting-with-bokeh-client), and I would say that demonstrating it so prominently for so long was a mistake on our part. It is occasionally useful for testing, but nothing else.

So what is the good/intended way to use the Bokeh server? The answer is to have a Bokeh app run *in the Bokeh server itself*, unlike the code above. This can be done in a variety of ways, but one common way os to wirte a simple script, then execute that script with

```
bokeh serve -show myapp.py
```

I don't have access to your "Accelerate.py" dataset, but a rough pass at updating your code would look like:

```
# myapp.py     
from numpy import pi, cos, sin, linspace, roll

from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

fa = open('Accelerometer.txt', 'r')

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))
fg = figure(width=250, plot_height=250, title="RT-Test")
fg.line(x='x', y='y', color="olive", source=source)
fg.x_range.follow = "end"

fg.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
fg.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
fg.background_fill_color = "snow"

curdoc().add_root(fg)

def update():
    line = fa.readline().split(',')
    x = float(line[0])
    y = float(line[1])

    # construct the new values for all columns, and pass to stream
    new_data = dict(x=[x], y=[y])
    source.stream(new_data, rollover=50)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 100)
```

Now if you run this script with the `bokeh serve` command, then any refresh will get you a brand new session of this app. It's also worth nothing that code written in this way is considerably simpler and shorter.

These kinds of apps can be embedded in Jupyter notebooks, Flask and other web-apps, or made into "regular" python scripts run with `python` instead of `bokeh serve`. For more information see [Running a Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) in the User's Guide.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I initially used your proposed approach but ended concluded that did not suited my needs (or more probably I am not fully understand how to integrate). The problem is that any refresh will restart a new session and therefore start the real-time streaming from the beginning. What I want is to integrate the real-time in a webpage... if the user goes back and forth on the menus and returns to the real-time visualization window I would like not to restart the entire session but to continue with the last values (That's why I was trying to use this).

Comment: The code above always starts reading data from the beginning `'Accelerometer.txt'`, but it doesn't have to. If you are continuously dumping data into that file, you can change the logic to start reading from the end, or anhy place in the middle that is appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Hi @dudas, Thanks for your precise answer, Is there any way to have reloadable HTML file in bokeh python file instead of calling infinite loop and press refresh in HTML file in the browser?